# Prevent range slider from resetting if user clears input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, slider

I have a range slider with input boxes. So far I have it mostly working but I need the thumb sliders to not reset in the middle if the user clears the input from the boxes. If a user clears the input I want the slider to stay at their current position.

Sliders reset in the middle if user clears and input

[image: Slider reset]

[image: Slider reset max value]

Here is the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/multi-range-slider-react-8jdvox)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of an advanced solution, but you can use debouce from lodash (or code your own debounce function, but use packages instead)

What you can do is have a debounce on the user input for the sliders
On the 'onChange' for your input component, debounce updating the slider value in your state, and have a check that if the input is null/undefined/empty, then don't update the state :)

I'm taking a break at work, but if you need me to provide exact code, I can do so ^-^

Answer (score 0):

it's not clear to me what you really want to do. Because let's say Min value is 40, and user clears the textbox with backspaces: first time, it's 4, the second time backspace is hit it will be empty. Do you want the slider stay at 40 or 4?

in any case, you can hold the value for previous state of min/max and if the new value of textbox is empty, don't update the slider state.

Comment: I just want the thumb sliders to not reset if the whole input is cleared(empty). I don't understand how to hold value? I tried to validate if the input is empty and just return immediately on my handlers but that prevents me from deleting the input entirely. I don't know if I'm doing it right.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the values of `input` and `slide` separately, that will be much more convenient and conforms to `React`'s `state` control.

#### Code fragment sample

```js
    const [min, setMin] = useState({ input: 0, slide: 0 });
    const [max, setMax] = useState({ input: 100, slide: 100 });

    const handleMaxChange = (e) => {
    const v = parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
    if (v) {
      if (v < min.input && !!min.input) {
        setMax({ input: min.input + 1, slide: min.slide + 1 });
      } else if (v > extremeMax) {
        setMax({ input: extremeMax, slide: extremeMax });
      } else {
        setMax({ input: v, slide: v });
      }
    } else {
      setMax((prev) => ({ ...prev, input: "" }));
    }
  };
```

#### Full code sample

[image: Edit TextField selectionStart]

Answer (score -1):

You can simply setup the slider like this:

```html
<MultiRangeSlider
      minVal={min ? min : 0}
      maxVal={max ? max : 0}
      ...
/>
```

Demo on [CodeSandbox](https://1jt6cr.csb.app/).